# Estauto & longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, stata

I'm trying to make my Stata output span several pages in the LaTeX document. With longtable, this isn't working. My table doesn't continue onto the next page (only the table notes are on the next page).

I saw someone suggested to edit the .tex file, as to add the  \begin{longtable} into it manually, but this seems like a very poor solution to me. What if my output changes? I can't find anything else relevant on tex.stackexchange about combining these.

Is there a way to encorporate longtable with the estauto command? Is it possible to already do this when Stata creates the .tex file?

I'd greatly appreciate any tips.

I tried this:

```
\begin{longtable}
\caption{reg1} \label{tab:reg1}

    \centering
      \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt} % space out the columns otherwise they are squished together
      \estauto{Tables/reg1.tex}{10}{c}
\begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item Note: Standard errors in parentheses. ***, ** and * indicate statistical significance at the 1\%, 5\% and 10\% level, respectively.

    \end{tablenotes}
\end{longtable}
```

Preamble:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{url}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{float} 
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{setspace}   %Allows double spacing with the \doublespacing command
 \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
%% maths
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}            % to reset the headers of tables 
\usepackage{rotating}           % for sidewaystable
\usepackage{booktabs}  % neatly formatting lines
\usepackage{threeparttable}   
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{dcolumn}    % aligning decimals
    \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}

\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
% *****************************************************************
% Estout LaTeX wrapper
% *****************************************************************

%%Original code developed by Jörg Weber: see
%% https://www.jwe.cc/2012/03/stata-latex-tables-estout/
%% and
%% https://www.jwe.cc/blog/


\let\estinput=\input % define a new input command so that we can still flatten the document

\newcommand{\estwide}[3]{
        \vspace{.75ex}{
            %\textsymbols% Note the added command here
            \begin{tabular*}
            {\textwidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \\ \bottomrule          % 08 Dec 2021. Add these slashes.
            \addlinespace[.75ex]
            \end{tabular*}
            }
        }   

\newcommand{\estauto}[3]{
        \vspace{.75ex}{
            %\textsymbols% Note the added command here
            \begin{tabular}{l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \\ \bottomrule          % 08 Dec 2021. Add these slashes.
            \addlinespace[.75ex]
            \end{tabular}
            }
        }

% Allow line breaks with \\ in specialcells
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}
}

\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}}% Thanks David Carlisle


%%%%%%%%%%% End of wrapper %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\providecommand{\keywords}[1]
{
  \small    
  \textbf{\textit{Keywords---}} #1
}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Where is your complete code?

Comment: Welcome. // Which parts of the preamble are obsolete to see your problem, when copying and compiling? (It's way too long ...)

Comment: It seems like you can just use `\estinput` instead of `\estauto` and leave the rest of your current code the same. Of course you should also provide a column specification to `longtable`, i.e., `\begin{longtable}{llllllllllc}` or something similar.